# Wordpress, вопрос-ответ

Tags: php, wordpress

Как можно сделать функционал, похожий на комментарии, но это будет вопрос-ответ вместо комментария? т.е. пользователь заполняет форму на фронтенде, админ отвечает.
Также над этой формой должен быть поиск из уже имеющихся вопросов, в котором можно отсортировать нужные вопросы с помощью тега select и чекбоксов.
т.е. можно задать вопрос, или можно найти ответ на интересующий вопрос с помощью поиска из имеющихся вопросов-ответов.
Можно было-бы доработать функционал комментариев, но нужен отдельно функционал комментариев с таким же поиском с помощью тега select и чекбоксов из имеющихся комментариев на отдельной странице, но это будут не комментарии а отзывы.
Проблема с созданием поиска из имеющихся вопросов-ответов, как это можно реализовать?
т.е. в админке должен быть раздел "Отзывы", а также должен быть раздел "Вопрос-ответ" по типу "Комментариев"

**P.S.**
https://wp-kama.ru/question/forma-obratnoj-svyazi
http://dontforget.pro/wordpress/dobavlenie-posta-proizvolnogo-tipa-s-frontenda-na-ajaxe-v-wp/
нашёл похожий пример

Comment: Как сделать - своим кодом. Посты кастомного типа, поиск по ним. Все решаемо.

Comment: @KAGG Design, вы имеете ввиду register_post_type?  получается произвольным циклом нужно выводить все посты нового типа "вопрос-ответ"?

Comment: Ну да, именно так.

Comment: @KAGG Design, подскажите пожалуйста, а как это можно реализовать, чтобы данные из заполненной формы сохранялись в новый тип записи? хотя-бы на словах, постараюсь найти похожий пример и реализовать. А поиск по записям не проблема сделать, такое уже делал

Comment: получается должны быть произвольные поля для чекбоксов и select

Comment: Непонятно, почему они должны сохраняться именно в стандартный тип записи. Всё в ваших руках - делайте свой обработчик формы и нём wp_insert_post() или wp_update_post().

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90760/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-word).